# Насколько широко можно употреблять прилагательное "старинный" в отношении людей и профессий?

Tags: стилистика

Когда слово "старинный" употребляют в отношении вещей, то вопросов нет. "Старинный приятель" тоже устоявшееся выражение и не коробит. Но когда читаю "старинные иконописцы", как будто бы что-то не то. Все равно, что сказать "старинный кузнец" или "старинный сапожник". А как думаете вы?

Answer (score 5):

Вы совершенно правы. Ведь слово старинный означает древний, сохранившийся с давних времен. Старинный замок, обычай.  Старинная живопись, мебель, одежда.

Comment: Значение слова Старинный по Ефремовой:  
1. Созданный, возникший в старину и сохранившийся до сих пор. // Ведущий свое начало, происхождение из далекого прошлого, из старины (о роде, фамилии и т.п.).  
2. Существовавший, живший в старину. // Устаревший, несовременный. // перен. Давно прошедший, минувший (о времени).   
3. перен. разг. Существующий долгое время.   

Формально второй смысл подходит и к кузнецам/иконописцам.

Answer (score 1):

Думается мне, что *"старинная вражда"*, как и *"старинный друг"*, — это гипербола, что-то вроде *"сто лет тебя не видел"*. Правда, не знаю, как к значению слова приписать иконописцев.

Comment: Нет, иконописцы не вписываются. Хотя почему бы им и не быть старинными?

Comment: По  отношению  к  человеку  вписывается,  если  речь  идёт  в  прошедшем  времени,  например  о  том, как работал  старинный  иконописец.

Comment: Согласна. И кузнецы в старину были другие. Но все-равно как-то не ложится на слух.

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю Вас, Ларf. Я тоже считаю, что права. Но заглянула в толковый словарь на грамота.ру и там, как пример употребления данного слова, "старинные иконописцы" и даже "стринная вражда". Вот чудеса.

Comment: Ну почему, как раз "старинная вражда" подходит - что-то вроде антонима к "старинному приятелю"  )))

Comment: Ну, да.  Если  она  ( вражда  )  ещё  тянется.